# Misplacement of Laravel Livewire 3 Tenancy File Uploads into Central Storage Instead of Tenant-Specific Storage

Tags: laravel, tenancyforlaravel, livewire-3

During the file upload process in directory folder livewire-tmp, files intended for temporary or tenant-specific storage seem to be directed incorrectly towards the central storage or primary storage. This results in an issue where files, despite being uploaded for temporary storage, are not correctly placed within the designated tenant's storage. Consequently, when accessed, these files appear empty or inaccessible, possibly due to residing in the livewire-tmp storage for the wrong or unspecified tenant.

- Files uploaded for temporary storage should be directed and accessible within the livewire-tmp storage specific to the corresponding tenant.
- Retrieval of files from temporary storage should yield the expected content without being empty or inaccessible.